# command line terminal in mac os x shows wrong version of Java

Tags: macos, terminal, java

I have installed Java 1.7 on my mac at

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In Command line I set the java version as

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

Now when i do `java -version`

It shows the correct java version  `'java 1.7'`

However, when i open a new terminal and do `java -version`,

it again shows wrong java version `'java 1.8'`   // I need to use java 1.7 for certain applications

How to make sure that correct java version is shown each time i open the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have both installed (OSX Yosemite iirc installs 1.8 by default)   try adding 1.7 to your java --alternatives   and or use the defined path (symlinks are lovely for this)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
which java
```

This should tell you where the executable is.  I agree with linuxdev2013, it is likely that you have multiple versions installed.  I imagine that the newer version is probably in your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap between installed versions of the JDK on the fly, within the terminal, using;

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'`
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'`
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'`
```

(use the same command in your `~/.bash_profile` to set the required default, too!)